# What is the default metadata size in temporary volume during a pvmove?

Tags: centos, lvm, metadata, pvmove

I ran into an interesting error when attempting to address a particular problem.

We had an issue where we have to move the extents over to new physical volumes because the metadata size was too small (255 sectors or 128k). We have increased the pvmetadatasize in /etc/lvm.conf to 32768 and use the size of 4K for the metadatasize on the new physical volumes, so we believe are good in that aspect. But then, as we were moving the last couple of volumes (they were about 500 gigs of data per volume), we ran got this error:

```
metadata too large for circular buffer
```

Which is curious, given the setting we made. We did eventually worked around the problem by re-running the pvmove command on to the various volumes until we moved on the data, though.

Looking at the man page, we see this:

```
1. A temporary pvmove logical volume is created to store details of all the data movements required.
```

My question is: Which default metadata size is used during the pvmove process? Is it the source PV, the destination PV or setting used in /etc/lvm.conf?

The systems are running CentOS 5.6, and most of the volumes we used are around 500 Gigs per PV.